# ssh commands to connect windows system in command line

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, ssh

I'm trying to connect windows PC in commandline but i'm unable to do that. Actually my requirement is to connect windows PC which is in the same network to use it's gpu resources. In linux we can do this by using the ssh username@hostname command. I don't want to use remote desktop/putty to connect. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `enter-pssession <computername>` in PowerShell

Comment: Thanks @SimonS. And also is there any way to transfer a file from one windows host PC to another Windows host PC which is in the same network in the command line ?

Comment: Can we use enter-pssession command in the windows command prompt instead of powershell.

Comment: yes you can `copy <sourcefile> <destinationfolder>` or `move <sourcefile> <destinationfolder>`. no, `enter-pssession` only works in powershell. but you can start powershell directly in cmd just by typing `powershell`

Comment: In my case <destinationfolder> is presented in the some other system in the network. In this case how can i copy my folder? Can i do powershell+enter-pssession from command prompt in between copy operation ?